# How do I express feeling included?

Tags: translation, expressions

How do I express feeling included in an event/community/etc? I often want to thank people for going out of their way (it seems) to make me feel included or at home.

I usually say something like 紹介してくれてありがとうございました but I would like to be able to emphasize/express that I really appreciate having been made to feel like part of the community/group of friends.

Is there a normal way to say this in Japanese? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

How about...

> あたたかく[迎]{むか}え[入]{い}れてくれて、ありがとうございました。

---

紹介してくれてありがとうございました would mean "Thank you for introducing/referring me (to someone)."